# Trouble seeting up Nginx for a jellyfin server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-jellyfin-media-server-ubuntu-20-04/) to set up me jellyfin server for remote access.
I have run this command :

```
certbot --nginx -d jellyfin.mydomain.eu
```

and have gotten this answer :

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for jellyfin.mydomain.eu
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain jellyfin.mydomain.eu
http-01 challenge for jellyfin.mydomain.eu
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: jellyfin.mydomain.eu
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://jellyfin.mydomain.eu/.well-known/acme-challenge/KgcK5tgDqPgMzkFzGyOELgjEU6WKMRxJbUFcX_-9uQI
   [213.186.33.5]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n    <html>\n        <head>\n
   <title>redirection jellyfin</title>\n   "

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

My server is running on Ubuntu and my domain is hosted by OVH if it helps...
Thank you :)

Edit : Here is my nginx.conf (I got it by using sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, I hope it's the right file.)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript t>
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: could you show us your `nginx.conf`?

Comment: just edited my post

Comment: please include contents of files included from here `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and here `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`